# VB.Net application highlights all files in background when running / getting focus

Tags: vb.net, focus, visual-studio-2005, selectall

I have an App that I inherited in VB6 and have ported mostly to VB.net 
When I compile / run the app - it highlights all the files in the current selected folder.

What makes it worse, is it's very difficult to search online as what search terms does one use?

The app was ported to VS 2005 - quite successfully - but this has me stumped...

I have tried commenting out all the code that's run on startup and it still does it, so it must be some sort of background thing...

Any ideas?
I can't find an old version of my app to see if it's changes I have made and I don't know where to begin.  See the image:
[image]

The top part is before I run the app, the bottom is once the app is running and has focus. I hope it makes sense

Also, if I'm browsing and then run the app, and go back to the browser, when my app gets the focus again, the webpage goes back to the top...

The folder is just an example - Basically when I compile (or later run) my App, if I go to Windows Explorer - when the app gets focus - whatever folder I am in has all its files highlighted. If instead of going to Windows Explorer, I go to a web browser, when the app gets focus the browser goes to the top (similar to Home).

There is Windows Integratio, but I have commented out what I can and still am no closer.

Does this info help?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. What is this folder list? Is it a part of your application? Is it windows explorer? When does it do this? Does your app use any windows shell / explorer integration ? You have provided us with insufficient information to even attempt a guess. Please [edit] your question to be more specific and include the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - after going back to the vb6 project and removing everything except for the 5 modules needed to startup and I eventually tracked the problem.

There was some code being called when two edit boxes received focus which called send keys home and end - hence it would go home - select all files to the end. I had deactivated one of the edit boxes to not receive focus and it helped temporarily(obviously until the other box got focus), but since deactivating the send keys when they get focus has helped. Albeit an arbitrary problem, maybe it will help someone in the future..